# Find a string between two other strings using a regex in php?

Tags: php, regex, string, substring

Is there a function in php to search a string and find a sub string based on it being between two defined character sets?

I am trying to search through a few files using a php script and grab a string from them.

the string i need is a URL, each file has a string that looks like this with a different url inside

```
/A << /URI (https://www.website/custom_ url_per_file)
/S /URI >>    //an actual linebreak in the code
```

I have all the files opening in a foreach loop, so how can i extract the url between the 2 strings $a and $b?

```
$a = /A << /URI
$b = /S /URI >>
```

Comment: You're looking for "non-greedy capturing group": `/$prefix(.+?)$suffix/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$string = '/A << /URI (https://www.website/custom_ url_per_file)
/S /URI >>    //an actual linebreak in the code';

preg_match('#/A << /URI \(([^\)]+)\)\s+\/S /URI >>#', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

will result to:

```
Array
(
[0] => /A << /URI (https://www.website/custom_ url_per_file)
/S /URI >>
[1] => https://www.website/custom_ url_per_file
)
```